# Getting touch coordinates using setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android, view

im writing my first android app (im not new to java). heres my problem:
i use an ImageView to show a graphic. I would like to write a method thas is called when the ImageView is touched and gets the touch coordinates as parameters.

Here is my current solution:

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            clickfield((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
            toast.setText((int) e.getX() + ", " + (int) e.getY());
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    });  

...

public void clickfield(int x, int y) {
   ...
}
```

I have two problems with this:
At first, the coordinates that it returns are not the real coordinates on the phone. my vm has a resolution of 480 x 800 pixels. As the ImageView is 480*480 pixels large, the y value should be between 0 and 480. The actaual value is between 0 and 320.This could be solved by multiplying it by 1.5, but this doesnt make sense to me.

The second problem is that the 480 * 480 Bitmap which is the content of the ImageView appears in the middle of the screen. I would prefer to display it at the top, especially beacause the the above code detects something like 0, 72 if i touch the up left corner of the image instead of 0, 0.
Which property of the image view do I have to change?

If there is any reference/tutorial that answers my question, it would suffice if you post a link.

my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <ImageView 
      android:src="@drawable/icon" 
      android:id="@+id/ImgTest" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:clickable="true" 
      android:layout_gravity="top">
    </ImageView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you post your layout XML it would help.

Comment: If you are setting the touch listener on the `ImageView` itself instead of the Activity then the coordinates might be relative to the location of your ImageView and that's what could be causing skewed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates you get relate to the the (Image)View to which the listener is attached.
Your image gets scaled to fit that view. So your view is 320px wide or high.
If you want to get the actual pixel coordinate, you have to calculate that from the Views width/height and the image ones. Almost like you did, but with a dynamic factor, since you will get different ones for every screen size.

The positioning of your actual image is also related to that. If the image is bigger or smaller than your view, it gets resized while maintaining its aspect ratio. If this doesn't match your screens aspect ratio, you will get some borders. To position the image on top of your layout, you should let the `ImageView` automatically resize its height to the required size of the image. You can do that via setting the `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` in your layout file (inside the `ImageView` tag). If it still stays in the middle, you probably have to also adjust your outer layouts gravity. See `android:gravity` (what you want here is `top`).

Comment: As you can see in the pixel sizes i posted above, the bitmap ist not resized. it is 480 pixels wide and 480 pixels high and it is displayed width exactly these values. The properties of the ImageView were already set like you suggest. But it is still not displayed at the top.

Comment: Just set up a small test project to check that. I can't reproduce both issues on a 2.2. 480x800 device. What android version are you using? I zipped the project, check if theres something different. Also note that your namespace is missing the `http://`, which gave me a crash on startup. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17220543/example.zip

Comment: Also works there for me. Maybe there something off with using toasts. Try using the `Log` class to check your coordinates, drawing is usually really slow in the emulator, and with a lot of touch events per second the toast mechanism may get a bit overloaded.

Comment: im not missing the http://. it seems to have got lost while this site turned it into a link. sorry about that.

Comment: i could comprehend if the toast didnt show anything at all. but why should it change the string to something else? i made a textview to display the coordinates and got the same result.

Comment: Was just a guess in the blue to be honest. Did that project work for you?

Comment: i opened your example (great thanks for your effort) and all works as i aimed to implement it in my project. maybe its important to say that the bitmap that is displayed in my project is generated during runtime and then put on the ImageView with setImageBitmap(Bitmap) using a Canvas, Bitmap and Paint class.

Comment: Mh I don't know. I mean it should not, but obviously does. Can you post your generation code?

Comment: I just changed the size of the bitmap to 320x320px. Now everything works. It is displayed at the top of the screen and the pixels are displayed between 0 and 320 (what would make sense now). But the image is obviously blurry. maybe the problem relates to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (the paragraph about Density Independence)